# ENTER event for jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am new to javascript; thus, it question may seem to be naive. I have a simple jQuery function as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtValue').keyup(function(){
        sendValue($(this).val());   

    }); 

});
```

This sends immediately when a letter is typed in

I explored [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/), but I was unable to find an event for ENTER. I want to run the function when I typed all letters and pressed ENTER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `keyCode` property of the event object. 13 represents the Enter key:

```
$('#txtValue').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        sendValue($(this).val());   
    }
});
```

The `keyup` event will fire every time a key is released. There is no way to selectively fire the event, but you can choose when to handle it!

**Edit**

It's actually better to use `event.which`, to deal with all browsers, as jQuery normalises the event object to help.

Comment: +9000 points for being the only person on this page to use identity operators instead of comparison.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an event for an individual key, you'll need to bind the `keypress` event and see if the keyCode is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (`13`):

```
$('#txtValue').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    //do stuff
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //-or-
    //return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

there's no event for ENTER you have to check every key and then if evt.keycode == 13 you have an ENTER

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add some logic to your event handler to check to see which key triggered the event:

```
$(function(){
    $('#txtValue').keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which == 13){
            // enter was pressed
        }
    });
});
```